# How to find the following type of set with computation time less than O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, set, time-complexity

[image: Consider the following set to understand the problem.]

Here 5 different sets are shown. S1 contains 1. Next set S2 is calculated from S1 considering the following logic:

1. Suppose Sn contains {a1,a2,a3,a4.....,an} and middle element of Sn is b.
2. Then the set Sn+1 contains elements {b,b+a1,b+a2,......,b+an}. Total (n+1) elements. If a set contains even number of elements then middle element is (n/2 +1) .

Now, if n is given as input then we have to display all the elements of set Sn.
Clearly it is possible to solve the problem in O(n) time.

we can compute all the middle element as (2^(n-1) - middle element of the previous set + 1) where s1 ={1} is base case. In this way O(n) time we will get the all middle elements till (n-1)th set. So, middle element of (n-1)th set is the first element of the nth set set. (middle element of (n-1)th set + middle element of (n-2)th set) is the middle second element of the nth set. In this way we will get all the elements of nth set.
So it needs O(n) time.

Here id the complete java code I have written:

```
public class SpecialSubset {
private static Scanner inp;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int N,fst,mid,con=0;


    inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    N=inp.nextInt();
    int[] setarr=new int[N];
    int[] midarr=new int[N];
    fst=1;
    mid=1;
    midarr[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
    {
        midarr[i]=(int) (Math.pow(2, i)-midarr[i-1]+1);
    }
    setarr[0]=midarr[N-2];
    System.out.print(setarr[0]);
    System.out.print(" ");
    for(int i=1,j=N-3;i<N-1;i++,j--)
    {
        setarr[i]=setarr[i-1]+midarr[j];
        System.out.print(setarr[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");


    }
    setarr[N-1]=setarr[N-2]+1;
    System.out.print(setarr[N-1]);



}
```

}

Here is the link of the Question:

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler103

IS it possible to solve the problem with less than O(n) time?

Comment: `Clearly it is possible to solve the problem in O(n) time`. It's not clear to me. The obvious algorithm is `O(n^2)` I think.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I have updated the statement accordingly..

Comment: since `S(n)` contains `n` numbers how do you expect  do display them in less than `O(n)`?

Comment: @svs as I seen same problem somewhere and I have written a code of complexity O(n) and it is taking 2n running time still it shows time limit exceeded. So either it should have an algorithm with time complexity less than O(n) or we can optimize the constant factor.

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee you can't have an algorithm with complexity less than O(n). I guess you might optimize the constant but it doesn't seems feasible. `2n` is so much good already.

Comment: @svs I am unable to solve the problem within given running time but i have seen people solved it.. So it must have running time better than 2n or O(n) whatever.

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee maybe your code is not optimized? have you considered that?

Comment: @svs If you wish I can share may java code here.

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee sure

Comment: how big `N` can be? Also you said `have seen people solved it`. Is this problem from some competition, or? If yes, can you link the problem's submission site?

Comment: max value of N is 10^6 .. I know then the value will exceed the limit of integer. I can manage it using 'BigInteger' but what about the running time.?

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee I owe you an apology. I'm now fairly sure it is `O(n)`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

@Paul Boddington has given an answer that relies on the sequence of first numbers of these sets being the Narayana-Zidek-Capell numbers and has checked it for some small-ish values. However, there was no proof of the conjecture given. This answer is in addition to the above, to make it complete. I'm no HTML/CSS/Markdown guru, so you'll have to excuse the bad positioning of subscripts (If anyone can improve those - be my guest.

## Notation:

Let a<sup>i</sup><sub>j</sub> be the i-th number in the j-th set.
I'll also define b<sub>j</sub> as the first number of the `j-2`-th set. This is the sequence the proof is about. The -2 is to account for the first and second `1` in the Narayana-Zidek-Capell sequence.

## Generating rules:

The problem statement didn't clarify what "center number" is for a even-length set (a list really, but whatever), but it seems they meant the "center right" in that case. I'll denote the rules numbers in bold when I use them below.

1. a<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> = 1
2. a<sup>1</sup><sub>n</sub> = a<sup>ceil(<sup>n+1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)</sup><sub>n-1</sub>
3. a<sup>i</sup><sub>n</sub> = a<sup>1</sup><sub>n</sub> + a<sup>i-1</sup><sub>n-1</sub>
4. b<sub>n</sub> = a<sup>1</sup><sub>n-2</sub>

## Proof:

First step is to make a slightly more involved formula for a<sup>i</sup><sub>n</sub> by unwinding the recursion a bit more and substituting `b`:

5. a<sup>i</sup><sub>n</sub> = Σ a<sup>1</sup><sub>n-j</sub> = Σ b<sub>n-j+2</sub> for `j` in `[0 ... i-1]`

Next, we consider two cases for b<sub>n</sub> - one where `n` is odd, one where `n` is even.

**Even case:**
b<sub>2n+2</sub> = a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n</sub> =
 **2** = a<sup>ceil(<sup>2n+1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)</sup><sub>2n-1</sub> = a<sup>n+1</sup><sub>2n-1</sub> =
 **3** = a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n-1</sub> + a<sup>n</sup><sub>2n-2</sub> =
 **2, 4** = b<sub>2n+1</sub> + a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n-1</sub> =
 **5** = 2 * b<sub>2n+1</sub>

**Odd case:**
b<sub>2n+1</sub> = a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n-1</sub> =
 **2** = a<sup>ceil(<sup>2n</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)</sup><sub>2n-2</sub> = a<sup>n</sup><sub>2n-2</sub> =
 **3** = a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n-2</sub> + a<sup>n-1</sup><sub>2n-3</sub> =
 **4** = 2 * b<sub>2n</sub> + (a<sup>n-1</sup><sub>2n-3</sub> - a<sup>1</sup><sub>2n-2</sub>) =
 **2** = 2 * b<sub>2n</sub> + (a<sup>n-1</sup><sub>2n-3</sub> - a<sup>n</sup><sub>2n-3</sub>) =
 **5** = 2 * b<sub>2n</sub> - b<sub>n</sub>

These rules are the exact sequence definition, and provide a way to generate the `n`th set in linear time (as opposed to quadratic when generating each set in turn)

Comment: The indices are very, very confusing, but this is correct. The only mistake (I think) is that in the even case it should be `2, 4 = b2n**+1** + a12n-1 =`. Good answer!

Comment: Nice explanation and really good proof!! Appreciate all your hard work. But   kindly could you explain how much efficient your algorithm is with respect to the one described by me. To generate the numbers we do not have to use such a complex definitions. Mathematically your proof is really good but how much efficient it is with respect to computational time, though it is linear but what about the constant factor associated with it?

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee Asymptotically the algorithms are the same (linear). It's fairly obvious that a sublinear algorithm is not possible. However, your algorithm is actually wrong (diverges from the actual result starting with `N=8`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out!! Starting from N=8 my code is giving wrong result.Let me check the time needed to execute your algorithm (as a code) as it is giving correct series.!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest numbers in the sets appear to be the [Narayana-Zidek-Capell numbers](https://oeis.org/A002083)

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, ...
```

The other numbers are obtained from the first number by repeatedly adding these numbers in reverse.

For example,

```
S6 = {11, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24}
        +6  +3  +2  +1  +1
```

Using a recurrence for the Narayana-Zidek-Capell sequence found in that link, I have managed to produce a solution for this problem that runs in `O(n)` time. Here is a solution in Java. It only works for `n <= 32` due to `int` overflow, but it could be written using `BigInteger` to work for higher values.

```
static Set<Integer> set(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n + 2];
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 2; i++) {
        if (i <= 2)
            a[i] = 1;
        else if (i % 2 == 0)
            a[i] = 2 * a[i - 1];
        else
            a[i] = 2 * a[i - 1] - a[i / 2];
    }
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = n + 1; i >= 2; i--) {
        sum += a[i];
        set.add(sum);
    }
    return set;
}
```

I'm not able to justify right now why this is the same as the set in the question, but I'm working on it. However I have checked for all `n <= 32` that this algorithm gives the same set as the "obvious" algorithm, so I'm reasonably sure it's correct.

Comment: Complexity does not depend on language used. It seems the explanation you have given will take O(n) time not O(n^2). Because you are using loop twice but not one inside another. So it will take O(n)+O(n)=O(2n)=O(n).

Comment: @souravbhattacharjee All I meant about languages is that I don't understand all the algorithms in that link because I can't interpret them. The second loop is obviously `O(n)`, no arguments there. But generating the first `n` terms of `1`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `6`, `11`... is - I think - `O(n^2)`. I could be wrong, but it definitely isn't obvious.

Comment: Please provide the proof for your assertion.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I proved the conjecture, however ended up with a *slightly* different representation of the series (had 2 leading 1s, instead of 3). That, coupled with the fact that the OPs code is wrong starting with `n = 8` meant that I realized my mistake too late to retract the vote. I won't spoil you the fun of proving it yourself, but if you'd like a hint, ping me! (Or when you finish and incorporate it in your answer - so I can retract the vote)

Comment: @Ordous I knew there were too many terms at the beginning of the sequence, but I was too tired when I wrote this to figure out how the recurrence changes when the indices change. `a[0]` isn't even used, so the code can clearly be improved. You should put your proof in an answer. I'll upvote if it convinces me. I won't hold your downvote against you :)

Comment: @PaulBoddington Done! Though there may be a mistake or two (or more...) because getting all the indices, subscripts and superscripts is so damn difficult here.